# Angular: How to manage invalid url

Tags: angular

Angular how to manage invalid url errors:

Here is my working url:

`http://192.168.0.1:4200/jobs/quick-worker-list/1306/1`

When i hit this url:

`http://192.168.0.1:4200/jobs/quick-worker-list`

Than, how can I manage such error with angular-router?

Answer (score 1):

i hope you have a router config for this then you need to configure into your route config object

create a component for page not found

and add

```
{path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
```

it will Show the 404 page for any routes that don't exist.